# Input System - how to get an action map by index/name

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Player Input component, and assigned to it is an actions asset. The asset has two action maps. Can I access an action map by name/index, because I want to access the action map even when it is inactive, so I can't use currentActionMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindActionMap`, a function in `PlayerInput`.

For example, to find the action map named "UI": `playerInput.actions.FindActionMap("UI");`

[unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputActionAsset.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputActionAsset_FindActionMap_System_String_System_Boolean_)